Sum of powers (geometric series) of state transition matrix
I am working discrete time Markov chain analysis for some large state transition graph. I want to find the rewards/cost to reach from the init state to the terminal/accepting states.
I have the state transition probability matrix M (n x n sparse matrix), and expected cost matrix C (n x n sparse matrix) for each transition, and the initial distribution vector v. (For most common case, v[0] = 1 and v[i>0] = 0, if this helps in speeding up some computation)
From my understanding, to compute the steady state distribution, we won't need to do multiple with the distribution vector and to compute the steady state, we just get the matrix powers, so M -> M^2 -> M^4 -> M^8 and so on, and we can pick the first column/row depending on how we represent the matrix as the stationary distribution.
This I assume is fast enough. But for cost estimation, I am a little confused.
After one time step, the cost incurred so far will be
c1 = v_0 * C, then for the next time step
c2 = v_1 * C = v0 * M * C,
extending this,
c_n+1 = v_n * C = v0 * M^n * C
And the total cost will then be
c1 + c2 + c3 + ...
= v0 * C + v0 * M * C + v0 * M^2 * C + .... V0 * M^n * C
= v0 *(1 + M + M^2 + M^3 + ... + M^n) * C   # Because matrix multiplication is distributive
My question is, this resembles geometric series that would converge to
1/(1-M) if n tends to infinity or (1-M^n)/(1-M).
Can this formula applicable to matrices as well?
Follow up question: If we have a markov chain where some states are absorbing and some states that form a cycle that never has a path to an absorbing node. I need to know if we can still obtain the stationary distribution and absorbing probabilities and cost to absorption when it converges. Does using the absorption matrix decomposition to [[Q R][0 I]] and related formulas still work?

An additional question, from my understanding this gives the expected cost to reach the terminal states. Is it possible to obtain histogram also effectively? Let us say a simple example, from an init state a, with a coin toss, if you head a head go to an absorbing state b. On tail in state a, it remains in a. In this case, the expected time to reach the terminal state is 2. [H, TH, TTH,...] => [1+0.5+0.25+...]=2
Here, I want to get a histogram like [(0.5p, 1),(0.75p,2),(0.875,3)...]

have you checked whether your matrix is diagonalisable? then you are just doing scalar multiplication of the diagonal elements wrt geometric series, yes that will work, assuming (I-M) has an inverse what histogram are you talking about?
the stationary distribution?

Your approach is inefficient, but your intuition is good.  Since any matrix $M$ commutes with itself, you can check your guess by multiplying term by term: $$(1+M+M^2+\cdots)(1-M) = (1+M+M^2+\cdots)-(M+M^2+M^3+\cdots)\=1+(M-M)+(M^2-M^2)+\cdots = 1,$$ showing that the series equals $(1-M)^{-1}$ provided the term-by-term multiplication and rearrangement of terms are justified. That requires the series to converge absolutely.  @seanv507 It doesn't matter whether the matrix is diagonalizable.

As an example of how to do these calculations in practice, see (for instance) my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/202393/919 that works through a significant problem in detail.  There are other methods when $M$ has special forms; see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/155562/919 for one example.

@whuber, my diagonalisation comment was related to inefficiency of calculating steady state distribution. but in any case, for that we just solve v(M-I)=0..?

@seanv507 I appreciate your clarification.  I think you're right, subject to a typographical correction: any solution $v$ of the system of linear equations $v(I-M)=I$ would give the inverse of $I-M.$  The problem is that a Markov transition matrix always has an eigenvalue of $1$--that is, it's always the case that there is an $x$ for which $(I-M)x=0.$  This creates convergence issues and shows $I-M$ is not invertible!  As a simple example, consider $M=\pmatrix{p&1-p\0&1},$ representing a stochastic transition to an absorbing state.  Here, $I-M=\pmatrix{1-p&p-1\0&0}$ has no inverse.

Thanks @whuber. I see the issue, and most of my use cases have absorbing states. From my understanding , I need to decompose them to [[Q R][0 I]] following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain.
But there is one more edge case. To be an absorbing markov chain, (1) there is at least one absorbing state and (2)it is possible to go from any state to at least one absorbing state in a finite number of steps. There are some cases in my use case, where there will be some absorbing states, but there will be some states that won't lead to an absorbing state. Will this still work?

If you might never get to an absorbing state, that creates the possibility of infinite expected total cost.

@whuber that's true. Okay, in that case, I will probably first find the stationary distribution, and make them all absorbing states, and use this decomposition, and filter out the results. Thanks.
Also, I added some clarification to the histogram part of the question.

@seanv507 thanks for the response. I added some more clarification to the question on histogram. Let us say a simple example, from an init state a, with a coin toss, if you head a head go to an absorbing state b. On tail in state a, it remains in a. In this case, the expected time to reach the terminal state is 2. [H, TH, TTH,...] => [1+0.5+0.25+...]=2 Here, I want to get a histogram like [(0.5p, 1),(0.75p,2),(0.875,3)...] What is the efficient way to get this?

@whuber For the absorbing markov chain, once it is decomposed as [[Q, R], [0, I]], how to get the total cost. That is, what is the equivalent of,
v0 *(1 + M + M^2 + M^3 + ... + M^n) * C when M = [[Q, R], [0, I]] block matrices?

I believe you want to compute the distribution of time to absorption and use that to compute the expected cost.  After all, $n$ is not fixed: it is random.  But since the analysis in your post doesn't do that expectation calculation, I'm unsure what it is you are really trying to achieve here.

@whuber In the previous comment, I was talking about find the expected cost not the distribution. The expected cost of the markov chain is given by
v0 *(1 + M + M^2 + M^3 + ... + M^n) * C as derived in the question. This will be slow for large matrix (millions of states) but the geometric series trick doesn't work because it is absorbing chain. So I understand I need to decompose the matrix to [[Q R] [0 I]]. But from here, I am not sure how to do the equivalent of v0 *(1 + M + M^2 + M^3 + ... + M^n) * C

Your formula cannot possibly be an expected cost, because it depends on the random vareiable $n,$ whereas the expected cost is a number.

This one, I am a quite sure. (Probably, I mixed by matrix multiplication and element wise multiplication) v0 . (1 + M + M^2 + M^3 + ... + M^n) * C, returns an array, that we need to sum to get the final answer though. C is the nn matrix with the cost for each edge. Then, MC (element-wise product) is the expected cost of each transition v0 . M gives the probabilities of being the next state. Similarly (v0 . MC) gives the expected costs of arriving at each of the nodes from prev state. sum(v0.MC) gives the total cost of that 'iteration'.
